# Call a void method in Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am working on a C# console project, but I am yet totally new in C#.  My question is: can I call a void method in  `Console.WriteLine();`? Maybe something like

```
static void ChangeColor()
{
   Console.backgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
};

Console.WriteLine("Hello *Calling method *ChangeColor();* * my friend!");
```

An example from my code:

```
                Console.Write(
$@"
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                                                  |
|                         __     __                                                                |
|                        / / \__/\ \                                                               |
|                        \/| /\/\|\/                                                               |");
                DarkBlueTxt();
                Console.Write(
$@"
|                        __||o o||__                                                               |
|                       / . \__/ .  \                                                              |
|                      /.  .(__).  . \                                                             |
|______________________\ .  /__\ .   /_____________________________________________________________|");
```

Comment: `Console.Write("Hello "); ChangeColor(); Console.Writeline("my friend")`?

Comment: a void method does not return **anything**, so you surely cannot use it as parameter to another one.

Comment: The statement must be inside a method/procedure.  You have it outside a method.

Comment: @canton7 This is an option, but I have a lot of code, so I am searching for something more flexible that I can use.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know that it doesn't return anything, but is there no way to call inside another one?

Comment: @Amer: `Console.Write`/`WriteLine` expects something that can be written to the console, so a string. You can't pass a method that does something and does not return  anything. You could call a method that returns a string though. `Console.WriteLine($"Hello {GetFriendsName()}, my friend!"); `

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've edited the post with a snippet of my code where I am facing that problem. When I set that brackets {} around my function i get this error: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Comment: @Anu6is The thing is that I only need to use this methods the rest I only use them once, and it is a small project so it doesn't need to be that big, I can leave it like this but I really wanted to learn something new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps make yourself a helper method:

```
void WriteWithColors(params object[] p){

  foreach(var o in p){
    if(o is ConsoleColor)
      Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)o;
    else
      Console.Write(o);
  }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
WriteWithColors(ConsoleColor.Red, @"
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                                                  |
|                         __     __                                                                |
|                        / / \__/\ \                                                               |
|                        \/| /\/\|\/                                                               |", ConsoleColor.Blue, @"
|                        __||o o||__                                                               |
|                       / . \__/ .  \                                                              |
|                      /.  .(__).  . \                                                             |
|______________________\ .  /__\ .   /_____________________________________________________________|");
```

The compiler will bundle your mix of Colors and strings up into an object array and then the loop in the method goes through it either changing the color or printing the string depending on what it is (a color or a string)

You don't need $ on the head of a string if you don't use {placeholders} within the string btw

Comment: I will try it and I will let you know about it thanks!

Comment: You can do `if (o is ConsoleColor c) { Console.BackgroundColor = c; }` and save yourself a cast

Comment: I guess OP wants a feature to insert a string somewhere like `[DarkBlue]` and then atomatically the part that comes after it will be written to the console in DarkBlue color.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can heavily abuse the new C# 10 [Interpolated string handlers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/) to let you write e.g.:

```
WriteColoredText($"First{ConsoleColor.Red}Second");
```

**Please don't actually do this in practice** -- it's a horrible hack which noone will understand. Use [@CauisJard's answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235244/1086121): it's probably clearer, and much simpler. But this is a fun exploration of the power of the new interpolated string handlers.

With that said, here goes.

First, we'll need to define our own interpolated string handler, We'll wrap `StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler`, as that mainly does what we want. However, when a `ConsoleColor` is written, we'll record this, ending up with a list of segments, where each segment is a section of text and the color to write it in:

```
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public struct ConsoleColorInterpolatedStringHander
{
    private readonly StringBuilder sb = new();
    private StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler appendHandler;
    private ConsoleColor? currentColor = null;
    public List<(ConsoleColor?, string)> Segments { get; } = new();
    
    public ConsoleColorInterpolatedStringHander(int literalLength, int formattedCount)
    {
        appendHandler = new(literalLength, formattedCount, sb);
    }

    public void AppendLiteral(string value) => appendHandler.AppendLiteral(value);
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value) => appendHandler.AppendFormatted(value);
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value, string? format) => appendHandler.AppendFormatted(value, format);
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value, int alignment) => appendHandler.AppendFormatted(value, alignment);
    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T value, int alignment, string? format) => appendHandler.AppendFormatted(value, alignment, format);
    
    public void AppendFormatted(ConsoleColor color)
    {
        Segments.Add((currentColor, sb.ToString()));
        sb.Clear();
        currentColor = color;
    }
    
    public void Finish()
    {
         Segments.Add((currentColor, sb.ToString()));   
    }
}
```

We then need to define a method which accepts this handler:

```
public static void WriteColoredText(ConsoleColorInterpolatedStringHanderhandler)
{
    handler.Finish();
    foreach (var (color, text) in handler.Segments)
    {
        if (color != null)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = color.Value;
        }
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}
```

We can then pass an interpolated string to our new `WriteColoredText` method. Any placeholders which contain a `ConsoleColor` cause the background color to change.

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

To get an idea of what's going on, switch to the [C# view on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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). The important bit is that the compiler has written our call to `WriteColoredText` into:

```
public static void Main()
{
    ConsoleColorInterpolatedStringHander handler = new ConsoleColorInterpolatedStringHander(10, 1);
    handler.AppendLiteral("Hello");
    handler.AppendFormatted(ConsoleColor.Red);
    handler.AppendLiteral("World");
    WriteColoredText(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check ANSI colors, but it requires a certain console mode which is explained in the link.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\u001b[31mHello World!\u001b[0m");
}
```

Source:
[Using ANSI colour codes in .NET Core Console applications](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/)

Comment: Thanks it is really a helpfull method, but in this project I can only use Visual Studio, but I will try your way in some bigger projects, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [Caius Jard's proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235244/13268855):

```
void WriteWithColors(params (ConsoleColor? Color, string Text)[] colorizedTextCollection)
{
    foreach (var colorizedText in colorizedTextCollection)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = colorizedText.Color ?? Console.BackgroundColor;
        Console.Write(colorizedText.Text);
    }
}
```

- Instead of receiving an `objec`t array, here you can pass color and text tuples
- With this approach the `foreach`'s body become a bit simpler

Sample usage:

```
WriteWithColors((ConsoleColor.Red, "red"), 
                (null, "still red"), 
                (ConsoleColor.DarkBlue, "blue"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody! You all have really good answers. To keep it simple for now I have placed each different colored part of the drawing in a different method and then called the parts and color methods one by one, that was the easiest way I think, even when I didn't want to do it like that but unfortunately what I wanted seems not to be existing. Thanks again for your answers!

Comment: If someone's answer is helpful, please accept it instead.